# Deleting a large directory using sftp

Tags: ftp, sftp, filezilla

I have to delete a directory with a large number of files on a GoDaddy server.

The hosting plan only gives me SFTP access without any in-browser file manager. So right-clcik delete folder is not an option.

So, I am using FileZilla to delete the folder and so far it has taken about 5 hours still a long way to go.

Is there any quicker way to delete the folder?

EDIT: No SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the alternative way is through SSH, but you might have to do it from a terminal or putty if you're on Windows.

On Linux:

- Open terminal
- Type `ssh your_username@your_server_domain_or_ip -p your_port_number` then press enter
- Enter your password (same as sftp passsword)
- Navigate to the directory above want to remove using the `cd` command.
- Say you're in `/home/jorge/` but and you want to remove `/home/jorge/pictures_folder` , type in `rm -rf pictures_folder`

On Windows:

- Download and install [Putty](https://www.putty.org)!
- Open putty and select SSH as the connection type and fill in your host/ip, port etc.. and click the Open button.
- Enter your password when it asks for it.
- Navigate to the directory above want to remove using the `cd` command on the terminal.
- Say you're in `/home/jorge/` but and you want to remove `/home/jorge/pictures_folder` , type in `rm -rf pictures_folder`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry should've mentioned this earlier - No SSH enabled.